How do transactions on the BTC blockchain get processed
From what I understand, miners deploy their GPU's and whatnot to solve complex mathematical problem and when they do, that doing is called discovering a block and thus they get rewarded with BTC(currently 3.125 BTC per block if I am not wrong). also, can miners earn less than 3.125 BTC from mining if they don't mine a whole block? can a part of a block be mined?
So, if I send my BTC from 1 wallet to another then who processes that transaction? miners? then how is it done since miners are solving math problems to discover blocks to earn BTC? This might be a very silly question but I have always wondered how this works.
